# Django templates: include template passing translated variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to pass the following into an included template via the Django [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#include) tag:

```
{% include 'btn.html' with
     btn_text='Hi '|add:first_name|add:' - Verify Email Now'
     btn_url=verify_url
%}
```

Therefore I can dissect the entire question in two parts:

*A.* Is it possible to have `first_name` added into the string in another, more elegant, manner *at template level*?

*B.* I need to have the string translated  *at template level* - is it possible?

I.e. what I intend to do (but is **not** syntactically correct) is the below:

```
{% include 'btn.html' with
     btn_text=
         {% blocktrans first_name as first_name %}
             Hi {{first_name}} - Verify Email Now
         {% endblocktrans %}
     btn_url=verify_url
%}
```

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831727/django-template-translate-include-with-variable?answertab=votes#tab-top):

Here is the given example:

```
{% trans "Load more promotions" as promotions %}
{% include "a_dir/stuff.html" with text=promotions %}
```

Answer (score -1):

To format the string, you could do that in the view and pass it in the context:

```
context = {'btn_text': 'Hi {0} - Verify Email Now'.format(first_name)}
return HttpResponse(context=context)
```

For translation of text, have a look at the following link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/i18n/internationalization/#trans-template-tag

Comment: Need to do it entirely at template level. Still, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: If really want to do so at template level, then I would suggest you make a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) and that because django doesn't provide any template tag to format strings.