# Django template: Translate include with variable

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a template in which you can pass a text variable. I want to include this template into another one but with a translated text as it's variable. How can you achieve this?

I would like something like this:

```
{% include "a_dir/stuff.html" with text={% trans "Load more promotions" %} %}
```

I tough about writing my own template tag that will perform a `ugettext` but then when creating the `.po` file, the text variable will not be taken automatically.

I don't want to do this work in the `view` since all our translations take place in the templates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put the translated string into a variable with the `as` syntax. For instance:

```
{% trans "Load more promotions" as promotions %}
{% include "a_dir/stuff.html" with text=promotions %}
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

A shorter way is

```
{% include 'a_dir/stuff.html' with text=_("Load more promotions") %}
```

which also works fine with variables

Comment: As a sidenote, here's where it's documented: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/translation/#string-literals-passed-to-tags-and-filters